# alter table add ... before `code`?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

ALTER TABLE `tada_prod`.`action_6_weekly`     ADD COLUMN `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE AFTER `member_id`;

works,

so i thought, to add the column as the first column i could do

```
ALTER TABLE `tada_prod`.`action_6_weekly`     ADD COLUMN `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE BEFORE `code`;
```

but i get a syntax error,
what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `tada_prod`.`action_6_weekly`
ADD COLUMN `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can add column only after particular field or at first not before.
The mysql query for add column after particular filed is:
`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name VARCHAR(30) AFTER column_name`

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

```
alter table table_name ADD column_name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL BEFORE specific_column_name;
```

This command is not allowed in mySQL syntax. If you use it I think you get

> " ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'before specific_column_name' at line 1 " message.

You can try:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL FIRST;
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending [@php](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2888956/php) answer, I think the rationale behind not including **BEFORE** is because all the effects of **`BEFORE`** can be easily achieved using **`AFTER`** and **`FIRST`**

For Ex:

Let's say, initially you have a relational schema like

```sql
+----------------------+
| name | age | address |
+----------------------+
```

and then for some reason you're compelled to add a new column `dob`*(date of birth)* just before `age`, but since **`BEFORE`** is not allowed, what you can do instead is insert `dob` just after the `name` using **`AFTER`** and very well achieve the same effect.

```sql
+----------------------------+
| name | dob | age | address |
+----------------------------+
```

> #### But what if you wanted to insert a new column `id` before `name`?

Since there is no column before `name` we cannot use **`AFTER`** to place the `id` column. In-order to resolve this, the language designers introduced **`FIRST`** which makes the desired `id` column as the first column of the table.

```sql
+---------------------------------+
| id | name | dob | age | address |
+---------------------------------+
```

Although I personally think **`AFTER`** and **`BEFORE`** would've made a more intuitive pair.