# Is it impossible to add a column in sql specifically before another column?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a column to my table before another column using BEFORE, I can't use AFTER because the column names before aren't a constant. This is what I have:

`ALTER TABLE testfyf ADD intake_10_2013 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL BEFORE url;`

Everything up until BEFORE is working.

Before anyone says anything about this, I know adding columns this way is not a good idea, but it is what my boss wants.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I have found plenty of examples that say this should work but it doesn't.

Comment: What error do you get? What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: MsSQL? I know this works in MySQL

Comment: @IAbstract afaik it does not work in MySQL.  The `AFTER` keyword does, but there's no `BEFORE` equivalent.

Comment: "the column names before aren't a constant" - so even if you make this work, it's not going to make things consistent, is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [alter table add ... before `code`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402310/alter-table-add-before-code)

Comment: @ajreal not a duplicate but similar. In this case, the `FIRST` keyword is not an option as it was for that question

Comment: Yes MySQL. I only get a syntax error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEFORE url' at line 1"

Comment: @Michael, yup, I double checked - you are correct. It appears that MsSQL does not allow this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/f1281533-ad45-4bdc-867c-a9369a02de80

Comment: @Bee -- convince your boss the order of column does not matter ...

Comment: LOL I wish. It is going by month and year. And the column is added based on data added to another table :S

Comment: @Bee: How many columns does your table have? This sounds like an un-normalized table.

Comment: Many, many columns. I do not find it efficient but it's not my call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL (if this is mysql -  you just tagged it `sql` generically) does not support a `BEFORE` keyword.  You will have to find out the name of the previous column and add it with `AFTER`.

You can use this statement to list the column names and determine programmatically with PHP after which one your new one should be placed.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename;
```

Here's a function that should return the column before 'url'. I didn't test it but I think it will do the job.

```
// Queries the table column information and returns the column name just before `url`
function get_column_before_url() {
  $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM testfyf");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['Field'] == "url") {
      // you should clean up your mysql resources before returning
      mysql_free_result($result);
      return $lastcol;
    }
    // Store the column name to return if the next one turns out to be `url`
    else $lastcol = $row['Field'];
  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$column_before = get_column_before_url();
$sql = "ALTER TABLE testfyf ADD intake_10_2013 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL AFTER $column_before;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) echo $mysql_error();
```

Comment: Indeed, more information here: ALTER TABLE Syntax - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Yes, apologies, it is MySQL. However, I cannot use the AFTER because as I said the column before is not a constant.

Comment: @Bee read the rest of my answer.  You can use `AFTER` once you've listed the columns and determined which one comes just before the `url` column.

Comment: @Bee I just added a function for you to find the column name.

Comment: Wow, I think my brain just broke a little. I am definitely a newbie. I will have to try and get this to work.

Comment: @Bee if you need additional clarification, let me know. In fact, I'm sitting here on wifi waiting for auto service so I'll just fill in the rest of the function. :)

Comment: If you could do that, that would be really great. Is the comment about the query call the one I used minus the `BEFORE`?

Comment: The only thing I am confused about, and it might be silly that I do not know, is am I leaving it as `$row['Field']` or am I changing the column name to something else?

Comment: @Bee leave it as $row['Field'].  That is how you'll get the cold listed by the database.

Comment: It worked with no errors but unfortunately it added the column after `url`.

Edit: I was wrong, it didn't add it at all.

Comment: @Michael What if url is the first column or doesn't exist at all?

Comment: @Brendan I never said it was a failproof function.

Comment: @Michael Indeed you didn't. My mistake. ;)

Comment: @Bee did you actually call `mysql_query()` after generating your `ALTER TABLE` statement? I didn't include that before.  Also  make sure you are using the correct table name in the `SHOW COLUMNS` statement.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I just realized and tried that, it didn't work so I took out the semi-colons from inside the statement and it worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `information_schema` to get the columns of the table in order:

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME
     , @n := @n + 1 AS column_id
FROM
    ( SELECT COLUMN_NAME
      FROM information_schema.columns
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourDatabase'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable'
    ) AS c
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT @n := 0 ) AS v
```

If you join the above to itself, you could get the name of the previous column and use `ADD COLUMN` with `AFTER`.

Comment: That will make it the first column. Not the column before `URL`

Comment: @Brendan: Right. Misunderstood the question.

Comment: Updated with different approach.