# Adding a column before another one in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm looking to put a column at the front of my table I know you can do

```
add_column :customer, :first_name, after: :last_name
```

but is there a way to do `:before`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're able to insert a column at the front of your table by using the `:first` option:

```
add_column :table_name, :column_name, :column_type, first: true
```

You can still use `:after` to handle all other positioning cases.

Answer (score 2):

These are mysql-specific options by the way.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/80e66cc/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/schema_creation.rb#L50-L55 lists the available options, looks like they only support `before` and `first`.

For what it's worth, PostgreSQL only supports adding columns to the end of the table.

Related question: [alter table add ... before `code`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402310/alter-table-add-before-code)